# ¿"Extenderse por" o "extenderse hasta"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, preposiciones

Me he cruzado con esta duda mientras escribía hoy y no he podido solucionarla.

> Algo es capaz de extenderse **hasta** una semana
>
> Algo es capaz de extenderse **por** una semana

Consultando con conocidos he encontrado adeptos a una y otra. También alguno me llegó a decir que debería decirlo así:

> Algo es capaz de extenderse **por hasta** una semana

Aunque esta última opción me suena de lo más extraño, no logro decidir entre las otras opciones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bueno, depende de lo que quieras decir, pero no tiene mucho que ver con el verbo extenderse (no hay preposición de régimen, al menos) y más con la marcación de duraciones de tiempo:

- …extenderse **por** una semana
  la extensión es de siete días, ni más ni menos
- … extenderse **hasta** una semana
  la extensión puede ser bien de siete días, bien de menos
- … extenderse **por hasta** una semana
  exactamente como la anterior (de un a siete días), ya que la preposición *por* es facultativa con duraciones explícitas (es decir, se puede decir que yo viví en España tres años o por tres años, en ambos casos, viví en España durante un período de tres años)

Ahora bien, hay algunas otras consideraciones.  Si ponemos un tiempo concreto (en vez de una duración de tiempo), *hasta* no implicará las duraciones menores:

- …extenderse **hasta** una semana **desde** hoy.
  la extensión concluirá en el mismo día de la semana, pero en la semana que viene

También hemos de notar que la palabra *hasta* tiene un significado casi al revés en algunos países (principalmente centroamericanos, pero también partes de México), en estos, significa «no antes de», por lo que en ellos

- …extenderse **hasta** una semana <sub>(Costa Rica, El Salvador, Guatemala, Honduras, México, Nicaragua)</sub>
  la extensión concluirá en algún momento después de un plazo de siete días.

En todo caso, aparte del aparente significado autoantónimo, hay poca diferencia en tu ejemplo, ya que dices «es capaz de…», por lo que podemos suponer que si es capaz de extenderse siete días o más, también sería capaz de extenderse menos de siete días.

Comment: Excelente respuesta, lo único: no puede extenderse más de siete días. Lo que quiero marcar es que va de 1 a 7 con cota superior en 7. De todas formas entiendo que son válidos todos los ejemplos

Comment: @MatiasAndina Sí, te entendí en eso. Solo mencioné eso de los países con el significado inverso de *hasta* para tener una respuesta más completa (seguramente alguien pasará por aquí y será hablante de uno de estos dialectos o le importará el curioso uso dialectal).

Answer (score 2):

Hola @guifa como mencionas tienes razón en el aspecto inicial de tu respuesta. Sin embargo soy mexicano y lamento decirte que al menos aquí, la preposición **hasta** no tiene ese uso en dicha expresión. Si bien tienes razón que su uso puede significar lo inverso, esto sólo ocurre en casos específicos por ejemplo:

> Abrimos **hasta** las 12 del día

En México esto puede significar que el negocio abre **a partir** de las 12 del día y no que cierra a las 12 del día (como debería ser por el uso de la preposición **hasta**)

El cambio de significado de **hasta** por su inverso me atrevo a decir que solamente ocurre cuando esta preposición puede ser sustituida por una expresión **a partir de** en un contexto estrictamente temporal. En el caso de la oración:

> Su duración se puede extender **hasta** una semana

la palabra **hasta** no tiene un contexto temporal, sino más bien uno cuantitativo y limitativo, es por esto que su significado no es el inverso al menos en México. Esta oración puede ilustrar un poco mejor a lo que me refiero con un contexto cuantitativo limitativo

> El costo puede llegar **hasta** 5 dólares

En este caso cualquier mexicano entenderá que el precio no pasará de 5 dólares.